# missing BY at '(' near 'ORDER' in expression specification

Tags: sql, hive, pyspark, type-mismatch, percentile

I get this error:

> u"line 2:34 missing BY at '(' near 'ORDER' in expression
>   specification\nline 2:41 mismatched input 'BY' expecting ) near
>   'ORDER' in expression specification;"

when I run:

```
customer_cutoff3=sqlContext.sql("""
select category,
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.4) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ty_spend) OVER (PARTITION BY category ) as low_spend_cutoff
from customer_cutoff2
where ty_visits>0
group by category
""").toPandas()
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Does this run without error against your database? Don't you need to group by ty_spend?

Comment: Hi Jacob, it's a numeric value. I am not sure if I've understood you correctly. I am grouping by category to see the selected percnetile value by next to it.

Comment: [('card_code', 'string'),
 ('category', 'string'),
 ('ly_spend', 'bigint'),
 ('ty_spend', 'bigint'),
 ('ly_visits', 'bigint'),
 ('ty_visits', 'bigint'),
 ('ly_last_shop', 'bigint'),
 ('ty_last_shop', 'bigint'),
 ('ly_recency', 'bigint'),
 ('ty_recency', 'bigint')]   ---------->these are my variable types by the way

Comment: So I'm going to have to go with a "no" you haven't tested the query?

Comment: This is the previous query which runs without any problems, ty_spend is already an aggregated value :

Comment: select card_code,category,
CAST(sum(case when year_flag in ('LY') then cat_spend  else 0 end) as BIGINT) as ly_spend,
CAST(sum(case when year_flag in ('TY') then cat_spend  else 0 end) as BIGINT) as ty_spend,
CAST(sum(case when year_flag in ('LY') then cat_visits  else 0 end) as BIGINT) as ly_visits,
CAST(sum(case when year_flag in ('TY') then cat_visits  else 0 end) as BIGINT) as ty_visits
FROM customer_cutoff1
group by card_code,category

Comment: What makes you think `PERCENTILE_DISC` function exists?

Comment: well, what's the equivalent of it in pyspark environment then :) it would be helpful if you've stated that :)

Comment: In any case the query does not make much sense. Please add a data sample including required results.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need an aggregate function [percentile_approx](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/percentile_approx.html)

```py
customer_cutoff3=sqlContext.sql("""
select category,
percentile_approx(0.4) as low_spend_cutoff
from customer_cutoff2
where ty_visits>0
group by category
""").toPandas()
```

window function `PERCENTILE_DISC` cannot work with `group by`